# Handlebar.js custom IF helper

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to write a custom handlebar helper that checks query params an either shows a field, or doesn't depending.

Unfortunately it's returning true or false to the view and outputting it, instead of evaluating true and showing the fields inside the if, or false and not showing anything.

Any help is very welcome.

```
{{#sortedByDeals}}
  <span class="deal-percentage">( {{ percent_off }} &#37; OFF ds:   {{ deal_score }})</span>  
{{/sortedByDeals}}


  Handlebars.registerHelper('sortedByDeals', function() {
    console.log("helper method called")
    var sortBy = getURLParameter('sort_by');
    if(sortBy === "deals") { 
      console.log("true")
      return true
    } else {
     return false
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own, by reading the docs more http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals.

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function(conditional, options) {
    // console.log("helper method called")
    console.log(conditional)

    var sortBy = getURLParameter('sort_by');
    if(sortBy === "deals") { 
      // console.log("true")
      return options.fn(this);
    } else {
      // console.log("else")
     return options.inverse(this);
    }
  });
```

and  in the template

```
  {{#if sortedByDeals}}
    <span class="deal-percentage">( {{ percent_off }} &#37; OFF ds:   {{ deal_score }})</span>  
  {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic block helper will work without using conditional helper. See more [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#basic-blocks)

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('sortedByDeals', function() {
    console.log("helper method called")
    var sortBy = getURLParameter('sort_by');

    if(sortBy === "deals") { 
      return options.fn(this);
     }else {
      return options.inverse(this);
     }
  });
```

In template,

```
{#sortedByDeals}}
   <span class="deal-percentage">...</span>  
{{/sortedByDeals}}
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass options to the function if you're calling it internally